# Search WebView using findAllAsync() and findNext(true);

Tags: search, webview

I'm trying to search words in my webView. This is my method for search:

public void filterWebView(String query){

```
if (query != null) {
    mQuery = query;
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                view.findNext(true);
                int c = view.findAll(mQuery);
                try {
                    Method method = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                    method.invoke(view, true);
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {}

            } else {
                view.findAllAsync(mQuery);
                view.findNext(true);

                try {
                    Method method = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                    method.invoke(view, true);
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
            }
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl(mDocUrl);
}}
```

And it works great for API versions < 16, but for API 16 and >16 this method find all words, but findNext() don't work.

If I set query and call this method 10 times in API <16 I get next result (if it exists) but in API >16 every time it highlights the same word.

What is wrong in second part of my method, after else{... ???

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for WebView.findNext: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findNext(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findNext%28boolean%29)

In particular, if you call findNext before findAllAsync, it will do nothing. Also please note that findAllAsync acts asynchronously, so you may want to register a FindListener on your WebView to get the results. (see [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setFindListener(android.webkit.WebView.FindListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setFindListener%28android.webkit.WebView.FindListener%29) )

Comment: Hi THX, I used findListener, but I don't understand how to get next result using it: http://pastebin.com/P5KUxKXr

Comment: It should be invoked for each match in the document, until `isDoneCounting` is set to true.